# Will a compass application run in iOS Simulator?

Tags: xcode5, compass-geolocation

I have written the code for a compass application and there seem to be no issues with it, except the fact that it does not run as a compass in the iOS Simulator. I assume this is because the Mac does not have an embedded compass/geolocation device in it - is this the case? Should I expect a compass not to run on the iOS Simulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the app can and does depend on to run. 
It could run, but you likely won't get any directional information. 
Many ios devices would be the same.